# Radius of Centroid Centered Circle Encompassing X Percent of Polygon?

Tags: polygon, computational-geometry, geometry-surface, centroid

I know how to calculate the centroid of a polygon and its area, from this I can calculate the radius of a circle centered on the centroid which encompasses 100% of the polygon: it's the distance from the centroid to the furthest vertex.

My question is: how do you find the radius R of a circle that encompasses X percent of the circle (where X% is < 100%)?

Here are some example geometries that I think would be good tests:
[L, Square, U and Star Test Geometries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBM5p.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The brute force method I have at the moment is to:

1) Start with a radius R half the size of the one needed to encompass 100% of the polygon

2) Approximate the circle with a 16 sided regular hexadecagon (area = 97% of a circle with the same radius)

3) Use one of the clipping methods (e.g. Weiler–Atherton) to find the intersection of the two polygons

4) Calculate the area of the intersection polygon(s)

5) Iterate the value for radius R until area of the intersection divided by the area of the polygon is within E% of (1.0262 * X%), where E% is the acceptable error in area and the 1.0262 multiplier accounts for the difference between using a circle and a hexadecagon.

Answer (score 0):

First decompose the polygon as a set of triangles with one vertex at the centroid and the two others forming an edge, with positive or negative orientation (depending on the edge orientation). The sum of the algebraic areas of the triangle will equal the area of the polygon.

Then consider the area of the intersection of a single triangle with a circle of growing diameter. This are first grows quadratically with a coefficient equal to the center angle, until a first vertex is met. Then the area grows slowlier and slowlier until the second vertex is met, and reaches the whole triangle area.

By adding these functions for all triangles, you will construct the global intersection area curve, which is defined piecewise as a function of vertex distance. You will first determine between which vertices the function reaches X% of the total area. Then, knowing the analytical expression of the piece of curve, you will find the exact radius value. Whether this can be done analytically or numerically depends on the expression of the tail of the triangle area.